# In Discover Meteor, how do I access the "author" username if using accounts-twitter?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm working through Discover Meteor and am using accounts-twitter instead of accounts-password.

When adding posts, `author` is set using `user.username` but this doesn't work with accounts-twitter.

How do I access the Twitter handle to set the author?

I've tried `user.services.twitter.screenName` but this does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue is related to publications.

Be sure to include the following in order to access Twitter profile info in the client.

**On the server:**

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
    {fields: {'services.twitter': 1}});
});
```

**And, in the client:**

```
Meteor.subscribe('userData');
```